# Not using colnames when reading .xls files with RODBC

Tags: excel, r, xls, rodbc

I have another puzzling problem.

I need to read .xls files with RODBC. Basically I need a matrix of all the cells in one sheet, and then use greps and strsplits etc to get the data out. As each sheet contains multiple tables in different order, and some text fields with other options inbetween, I need something that functions like `readLines()`, but then for excel sheets. I believe RODBC the best way to do that.

The core of my code is following function :

```
.read.info.default <- function(file,sheet){
    fc <- odbcConnectExcel(file)    # file connection
    tryCatch({
      x <- sqlFetch(fc,
                    sqtable=sheet,
                    as.is=TRUE,
                    colnames=FALSE,
                    rownames=FALSE
           )
      },
      error = function(e) {stop(e)},
      finally=close(fc)
    )

    return(x)
}
```

Yet, whatever I tried, it always takes the first row of the mentioned sheet as the variable names of the returned data frame. No clue how to get that solved. According to the documentation, `colnames=FALSE` should prevent that.

I'd like to avoid the `xlsReadWrite` package. Edit : and the `gdata` package. Client doesn't have Perl on the system and won't install it.

---

Edit:

I gave up and went with `read.xls()` from the `xlsReadWrite` package. Apart from the name problem, it turned out RODBC can't really read cells with special signs like slashes. A date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" just gave NA.

Looking at the source code of sqlFetch, sqlQuery and sqlGetResults, I realized the problem is more than likely in the drivers. Somehow the first line of the sheet is seen as some column feature instead of an ordinary cell. So instead of colnames, they're equivalent to DB field names. And that's an option you can't set...

Comment: I've had this problem too. The way I dealt with it was to write some manipulation code after the fact to drop bogus data and rename columns.

Comment: @Brandon: That's what I did as well, but it's still a bummer I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the Perl-based solution in the [gdata](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gdata) instead?  That happens to be portable too...

Comment: Alas, remember that client where I even have to make sure R doesn't have to connect to the internet? No way they'll allow me to add Perl to the set...

Comment: Calling the bluff.  Excel can too --- so who cares.  Time to get smarter clients?

Comment: have to be careful what I say here, but let's keep it on a slight disagreement between myself and the senior professor on the tasks of an academic statistical consultant. Plus, I hope to convince them to actually USE the database they have. Right now they pull the excel sheets from there, imagine. *facepalm*